# Difference between Pig and Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

What's the difference between Pig and Hadoop?
Does Pig operate on top of Hadoop and additionally offers Pig Latin to be able to fully exploit Hadoop's technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org) consists of 2 components HDFS and MapReduce.

- [HDFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#HDFS) is a distributed file system for storing large chunks of data, which is highly scalable & fault-tolerent.
- [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) on the other hand is the processing engine that can process data stored in HDFS. MR tries to bring compute to where the data is located (data-locality).

For designing algorithms to process/analyze the data stored in HDFS, MapReduce provides the following API's:

- [JAVA API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/package-summary.html) - allows the user to write MapReduce applications, generally in 2 phases [Mapper](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) & [Reducer](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html)
- [Streaming API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) - allows the user to write map & reduce in dynamic programming languages like Python/Perl/Ruby/Shell/...
- Pipes - allows the user to write map & reduce in C++

[Pig](http://pig.apache.org) & [Hive](https://hive.apache.org) on the other hand are the frameworks that sits on top of MapReduce and can convert the code written in PigLatin (data-flow language) or HiveQL (SQL like syntax) respectively to set of MapReduce jobs which saves a lot of programming time.